# Applying finite difference expansion to smooth but non-analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, finite-differences, newton-series

There is (//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) a generalization of the Taylor series that converges to the value of the function $f(x)$ for any bounded continuous function on $(0,\infty)$ using the calculus of finite differences.

Specifically, according to a theorem by Einar Hille, in "Functional Analysis and Semi-Groups", AMS Colloquium Publications **31**, *1957), p.300-327,

$$f(a+t) = \lim_{h\to 0^+} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \frac{\Delta_h^n f(a)}{h^n} $$
where $\Delta_h^0 f(a) = f(a)$ and for $n>1$, $$\Delta_h^n f(a) = \Delta_h^{n-1}f(a+h) - \Delta_h^{n-1}f(a)$$

This is closely related to the Newton series for $f(x)$.

I thought I would give this theorem a try on my favorite bad-boy function $e^{-1/x^2}$.  In order to keep the domain strictly positive, as required in the statement of the theorem, I move the interesting point a bit to the right by looking at 
$$ f(x) = e^{-\frac1{(x-1)^2}}$$
It would be nice to have some sort of series expansion (about $x=1$) that works, rather than always giving zero as the naive Taylor series does.

So the first step is to find those finite differences, and that is reasonably easy:
$$
\Delta_h^nf(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}e^{-\frac1{(x-1+kh)^2}}
$$

And now to expand about $x=1$, we have to plug that expression, with $x=1$,  into the theorem and take the limit as $h\to 0$ for each value of $n$.

And here is what puzzles me -- for all values of $n$, that limit is zero. For example, for the $n=2$ term we get
$$
\frac{t^2}{2!} \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/(4h^2)}-2e^{-1/h^2}}{2h^2}=\frac{t^2}{2!} \cdot 0
$$

What is happening here?  Is it that I'm not allowed to switch the order of summation on $n$ with taking the limit as $h\to 0$? If so, this theorem is of little practical use...

Comment: I see that you have created ([tag:newton-series]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/newton-series/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Comment: I have now done that.  Thank you for the tag-wiki link.